# Tree View File Explorer for Windows

Tags: windows, file-management

I would like a file explorer for Windows (10) that allows you to view everything, files and folders, in a single tree view, without having to open each folder to see a list of its files in a separate panel. It would be handy if I could also see the size and modification date, similar to the Details view in Windows Explorer. I.e., I would like something that merges the information types from the left and right panels in Windows Explorer.

Is this a thing?

Edit: Adding Detail

This is the view from TreeSize, which would be perfect if I could add folders. I am looking for this, but with all standard file actions available (drag and drop, delete, add folder):
[image: TreeSize File Tree, showing files inline]

Comment: For anyone in the future reading this- I contacted TreeSize, and they said they would take the suggestion and add the ability to create folders in the 4.7 version, but as the 4.6 version just came out, that could be a while. So, while it isn't an answer for me, might be for you.

Comment: FYI, the view shown in the original post says simply "TreeSize", but it must be added that there are three editions of TreeSize (Free, and two paid versions, Personal and Professional). This view inexplicably exists *only* in the Free version. I mucked around with the demo of Pro for half an hour before realizing this. The paid versions have the separate tree-on-the-left and details-on-the-right in separate panes like Windows Explorer, the exact thing I want an alternative to.

Comment: Actually now both versions pro and personal are like this.

Answer (score 1):

There is an application that I use called **ZTree**.  It's text mode, but otherwise, I think it does all you ask and more.

[image]

[Home of ZTree](https://www.ztree.com/)

Note, I have no affiliation with the author.  It used to be free.  But there is a charge for it now, with 30 days free trial.

Comment: I'll check it out and see. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: So close, but it still breaks off at the File level and puts the files off in their own section of the window instead of in the tree itself. It would be handy to have two panes in the window so I could focus on different parts of the tree, but the important bit is having the files in the same tree presentation as the directories.

Answer (score 1):

With a google search, I found **FileExplorer** tool.

https://github.com/omeryanar/FileExplorer

As per description, this one quite fast and have a lot of feature which Windows doesn't have. Also, I can see new folder option in snapshot. Quite worth a try!!

**Old answer:**

I use **WinDirStat - Windows Directory Statistics** tool which is GUI based and mainly used for disk usage purpose but also helpful as tree view explorer. The initial loading might take time as it's main purpose is for calculating disk usage.

Comment: I have used that one before, but I didn't think of using it as a file explorer. I will check it out for this. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Visually, the tree view portion of WinDirStat is perfect, but I don't see any way to create folders, so it's not quite suitable for my purposes, sadly.

Comment: Based on this suggestion, I tried TreeSize, which I use for the same purpose WinDirStat is intended for, and it is much faster due to not providing the pretty disk visualization, but it still has the same problem. You can drag and drop files within the existing tree structure, but you can't make new folders, that I can see. Thanks for the idea; I might use TreeSize in concert with Explorer to speed things up. :-)

Comment: Correct. There is no option to create new folder. No sure about command-line option. Also, the initial loading time doesn't make it a good candidate for explorer tool.

Comment: FileExplorer, unfortunately, has the same issue as the many other Windows Explorer alternatives I have been trying; lots of features that would be useful in everyday use, but you have to select a single folder to see the files in it. Only folders are shown in the tree. Thanks for the additional suggestion, though!